# How to attach IE8 only stylesheet in Zend 1

Tags: css, zend-framework

How do I attach a IE8 only stylesheet in Zend with viewhelpers

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for this case Zend view helper [headLink](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.headlink)

```
$this->view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/path/to/some/styles.css', 'screen', 'IE 8');
```

Answer (score 2):

well you can use conditional statements as follows,

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<style>...</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Follow this article [HERE](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)

And this article [HERE](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

Hope it helps..

Comment: Thanks for your help, got it working. Why do people down vote without leaving solid reasoning.